# Dispatch event from nested activity to container activity

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, dispatchevent

I have next UI hierarchy:

FragmentActivity > MapFragment (tabhost with one tab and LocalActivityManager) > MapActivity

How do i dispatch Search and Back key pressings from MapActivity to FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getParent() method in MapActivity returns FragmentActivity